# Excel file getting corrupted while downloading using PowerShell/Curl

Tags: excel, powershell

I am trying to download an Excel file from Artifactory to my local machine using a PowerShell/Curl script. The Excel file is getting created, but when I open a sheet I am getting the below message and there is no data in this.

> The file format and extension of 'DataSheet_DEP.xls' don't match. The file could be corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust its source, don't open it. Do you want to open it anyway?

```
curl.exe -k -u artifactory_TEMP:Password16 https://../artifactory/../DataSheet_DEP.xls --output  D:\ABC\Team Members\Datasheet\DataSheet_DEP.xls
```

Just to add Excel file is in 97-2003 workbook (.xls). I am able to download the file manually without any issue.

Comment: You are using **`curl.exe`** to download it, not `PowerShell`. It is irrelevant what shell (or shell script) you are using to start **`curl.exe`**.

Comment: There is no PowerShell code in your question. You're apparently using an external command (`curl.exe`) for downloading the file, which should download the file as-is. How are you opening the file after the download? What is the actual type of the file? (use e.g. [TrID](http://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html) to determine that)

Comment: Thanks for reply..I am opening it manually after downloading . File type is 97-2003 xls format

Comment: How did you verify that? You obviously did not use TrID as I suggested, b/c that would not identify the type as "97-2003 xls format".

Comment: I missed that part.. i dont have right to install external sofware.. i tried online site http://checkfiletype.com/  .please suggest if thsi is fine     The file type is:

File Type: Composite Document File V2 Document, Little Endian, Os: Windows, Version 6.1, Code page: 1252, Last Saved By: Devkant Krishnatrey, Last Saved Time/Date: Wed Apr 17 10:16:05 2019, Security: 0
MIME Type: application/msword
Suggested file extension(s): doc

Comment: That doesn't seem very reliable. TrID has an online version (link on the program homepage). Use that.

Comment: Thanks @AnsgarWiechers...I have checked it now..File Type is Generic OLE2 / Multistream Compound File

Comment: Please suggest now

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved now.. I was using wrong artifactory path. Thanks everyone who tried to help here